# How should I allocate memory to many (1000+) arrays which I don't know the size of?

Tags: memory, dynamic, cuda, neural-network

I am implementing a spiking neural network using the CUDA library and am really unsure of how to proceed with regard to the following things:

1. Allocating memory (cudaMalloc) to many different arrays. Up until now, simply using cudaMalloc 'by hand' has sufficed, as I have not had to make more than 10 or so arrays. However, I now need to make pointers to, and allocate memory for thousands of arrays.
2. How to decide how much memory to allocate to each of those arrays. The arrays have a height of 3 (1 row for the postsynaptic neuron ids, 1 row for the number of the synapse on the postsynaptic neuron, and 1 row for the efficacy of that synapse), but they have an undetermined length which changes over time with the number of outgoing synapses.

I have heard that dynamic memory allocation in CUDA is very slow and so toyed with the idea of allocating the maximum memory required for each array, however the number of outgoing synapses per neuron varies from 100-10,000 and so I thought this was infeasible, since I have on the order of 1000 neurons.

If anyone could advise me on how to allocate memory to many arrays on the GPU, and/or how to code a fast dynamic memory allocation for the above tasks I would have more than greatly appreciative.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any reason why you couldn't just work out of a single large memory allocation instead of many small ones?

Comment: The reason I intended to use many small allocations was that I wanted the 'structure' of the information to be similar to an adjacency list, that is, there is a list for each node in the network that tells you which other nodes it is connected to ( except in my case it would be a 'matrix' because I have 3 rows of information per node)- I thought this would avoid having many zero elements which would be the case if I used a large 3D array. Am I right in thinking these zero elements would use up memory?

Comment: There are only two options: use an available allocator (such as cudaMalloc, or malloc on the device) or create your own allocator.  If you're worried about speed, and have lots of small allocations, then creating your own allocator is probably the way to go.  This would involve issuing `cudaMalloc` once or a small number of times, then parcelling off pieces as needed, by pointer indexing into the allocated area on the device.  A large 3D array would simplify coding but have potential for much more wasted space.  A smart allocator would only peel off as much space as is needed.

Comment: Additionally, if you have 1000 arrays of ~1000 bytes each, that is only 1 MB which is tiny in the big picture of today's devices that have 1GB or RAM or more.  If your overall size is low, by all means, waste space and keep your code simple by making each element the max size (a fixed size allocator, or just the single 3D array approach).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, you can call `cudaMalloc` as many times as you want; however, it's probably not a good idea.  Instead, try to figure out how to lay out the memory so that neighboring threads in a block will access neighboring elements of RAM whenever possible.

The reason this is likely to be problematic is that threads execute in groups of 32 at a time (a warp).  NVidia's memory controller is quite smart, so if neighboring threads ask for neighboring bytes of RAM, it coalesces those loads into a single request that can be efficiently executed.  In contrast, if each thread in a warp is accessing a random memory location, the entire warp must wait till 32 memory requests are completed.  Furthermore, reads and writes to the card's memory happen a whole cache line at a time, so if the threads don't use all the RAM that was read before it gets evicted from the cache, memory bandwidth is wasted.  If you don't optimize for coherent memory access within thread blocks, expect a 10x to 100x slowdown.

(side note: The above discussion is still applicable with post-G80 cards; the first generation of CUDA hardware (G80) was even pickier.  It also required aligned memory requests if the programmer wanted the coalescing behavior.)